# Use a data pointer on an undeclared data variable

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function with the following prototype (that I can't modify):

```
void writeData(uint16_t add, uint16_t *data);
```

`*data` is supposed to point to an `uint16_t` variable. So in my code I use it like this for example:

```
uint16_t dataValue;
dataValue = 55;
writeData(0, &dataValue);
```

Is there a way to simplify the above code in order to use the function `writeData` without declaring the variable `dataValue`? Something like this, but with the correct syntax:

```
writeData(0, syntaxInCWhichPointsToTheAdressOfTheValueInsideBrackets{55});
```

If not, can we modify the value pointed in the same instruction line of the operator `&`?

```
writeData(0, &dataValue{dataValue=55}); // something like this but with correct syntax
```

I don't want to encapsulate `writeData` inside an other function.

Comment: Why don't you want to wrap `writedata` inside another function?

Comment: I know I could use a wrapper function, but my question was for culture purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complement to the other answers matching the point

> can we modify the value pointed in the same instruction line of the operator &

---

The comma operator allows to compute several expression and only keep the last one:

```
uint16_t datavalue;

writeData(0, (datavalue = 55, &datavalue));
```

will correctly assign 55 to `datavalue` just before passing its address to `writedata`

Comment: It still needs a declared variable.

Answer (score 5):

With C99, you can use a compound literal:

```
writeData(0, (uint16_t []) { 55 });
```

But it makes the code less readable in my opinion.

Comment: Alternatively, `&(uint16_t){55}` does the same thing as `(uint16_t[]){55}`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you **have** to declare a variable in C, in order to use it somewhere else. If this where C++, I'm sure you could do:
`writeData(0, (uint16_t)dataValue = 55);`, essentially declaring the variable "seconds" before you execute the function. Other than that, I'm not sure there's a way to "avoid" that, but, of course, I could be mistaken

Comment: Wait, doesn't this rule: `for(int i=0; i<=10;i++)` apply to this as well?

Comment: The `for (int i = ...` is a whole different story and it also works in C

Answer (score 0):

I think this [topic](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/) about l-values and r-values answers your question.

Your function

```
void writeData(uint16_t add, uint16_t *data);
```

Gets a pointer ( l-value ). You must pass it a pointer because this is how it is declared. This means passing an r-value is not possible ( there might be a work around with malloc, but I wouldn't recommend it ).